# Image resolution and image scale of air photo

Tags: scale, resolution

I was wondering if 2 aerial photos of different scales can have the same resolution. My understanding is they cannot as fine resolution images will only cover a small area and vice versa?

Answer (score 4):

Image resolution is defined as the ground-distance or ground-area each pixel covers. Scale is defined as the linear transformation between a map/photograph metric of distance and the real-world metric of distance.
On their own, either value does not exert an influence on the other. They are independent. If you print two versions of an aerial image, one 9in x 9in and and the other 18in x 18in, you have changed the scale of the image. You have not changed the resolution, as a pixel still covers the same ground area on either printed image.

Comment: @ Logan. This is a very helpful insight!